Issue with `bcryptjs` Password Comparison in Node.js and React
I'm having issues with bcryptjs while handling passwords in my application. Registering users works fine, but logging in using the same password is giving me errors. I have made sure that the password is correct, yet it still doesn't match. It seems that bcryptjs is not working for me as intended.
Here is my code for the login endpoint in Node.js:
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const UserModel = require('../models/user_model');

const router = express.Router();
const SECRET_KEY = 'secretKey';

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    console.log('Login attempt with email:', email);

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            console.log('User not found');
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid email or password' });
        }

        console.log('Stored user record:', user);

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        console.log('Password comparison result:', isMatch);
        if (!isMatch) {
            console.log('Password does not match');
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid email or password' });
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, SECRET_KEY);
        res.json({ token });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error logging in:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error logging in' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;

And here is the React code for handling the login form submission:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({ email: '', password: '' });
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5500/users/login', form, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            loadCart(); // Assuming you have a function to load the cart
            navigate('/profile');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error logging in:', error);
            alert('Invalid email or password');
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                value={form.email}
                onChange={(e) => setForm({ ...form, email: e.target.value })}
                required
            />
            <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                value={form.password}
                onChange={(e) => setForm({ ...form, password: e.target.value })}
                required
            />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Login;

Here is the console output:
Login attempt with email: alex.gray@gmail.com
Password comparison result: false
Stored user record: {
  _id: new ObjectId('666bc37b7280ededaca09d72'),
  fullName: 'Alex Gray',
  email: 'alex.gray@gmail.com',
  password: '$2a$10$YJoBVSDWBeJ4o6e47dAR5u0wFSPv.FkLN0qshs0oYDBXQn3aYYK7e',
  cart: [],
  __v: 0
}
Password comparison result: false
Password does not match

I am certain that the email and password are correct. The stored password in the database is hashed, and it appears to be correct as well. I've logged the stored user record and the result of the password comparison, and it consistently returns false.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have suggestions on what might be going wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: userschema:

// cart schema
const CartItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    // cart: [CartItemSchema]
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    cart: [CartItemSchema]
});

// Hash the password before saving
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    const user = this;
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});


Can you share two lines of more code about how did you salt & hash password during registration?Also share how did you define schema for password field.

const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
const newUser = new UserModel({ fullName, email, password: hashedPassword });
I'll add userSchema in post

You are hashing the plain text password twice. When your users first sign up don't hash the password. Just do const newUser = new UserModel({ fullName, email, password }); await newUser.save(). The save hook will then be triggered. Delete that user and start again.

Thanks, I can't believe I was stuck on this for so long and didn't notice. Thank you, really! I was having an existential crisis

The most likely cause of this issue is that the password hashing process during registration (userSchema.pre('save', ...) hook) is not being executed correctly or consistently. Specifically, if the user.password field is being hashed repeatedly due to incorrect logic in the pre('save', ...) hook, the stored hash in the database will not match the expected hash during login.
 userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        const user = this;

        if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

        user.password = hash;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});

